# Copy/Backup ext4 files to external ntfs hdd: Permissions etc

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, ext4

Normally I backup my files (from ext4 drive) to an external ext4 hdd. Now I want to copy/backup some files to an external ntfs hdd, so I have the possibility to access them from Windows, too.

- Is there something I have to take care of (permissions etc.)?
- Do I just copy the files or do I need to use a special program (rsync etc.) or specific cp parameters?
- Can I use the ntfs hdd also as a backup drive and restore the files to the ext4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ntfs doesn't store unix ownership and permissions without special configuration.  This generally doesn't matter to data files like documents or music, but if you are planning on backing up the whole system, the permissions will need to be preserved, so you will need to use something like `tar` rather than just copying the files.